# Rails: List all of Parent's children in Parent's Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

In my rails app I can create a client and a worker for that client. Currently, I'm able to list all the workers that have been created. However, this list includes the workers for other clients too.

How do I only list all the workers for a specific client in the client show page?

I have a feeling it has to do with my client#show method.

```
  class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /clients
  # GET /clients.json
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  # GET /clients/1
  # GET /clients/1.json
  def show
    @workers = Worker.all
  end


  # views/clients/show.html.erb
  <ul>
   <% @workers.each do |worker| %>
    <li><%= worker.first_name %> <%= worker.client.business_name %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ClientsController`, your `show` action should be showing a `Client`, but your code is fetching from `Worker`. You want something more like this:

```
def show
  @client = Client.includes(:workers).find(params[:id])
end

# app/views/clients/show.html.erb
<% @client.workers.each do |worker| %>
  <%= worker.name %>
<% end %>
```

Note: it looks like you also have a `set_client` method that is retriving the current `Client` and setting the `@client` instance variable. This is something of an antipattern; in many cases you retrieve data you don't need and make your actions harder to understand at a glance. A small amount of non-logic duplication is better than confusing abstractions!

Comment: I think I get it. With the code above I'm first including all the workers associated with the client in the instance variable @client. Then I'm calling the client's worker, therefore all the attributes associated with that worker (i.e name).

Comment: Coreyward, I don't quite understand your note. Is it okay to leave it as it is or should I change it?

Comment: Well done on using `.includes` to eager load the `:workers`. Doing this will improve performance by reducing the number of database queries depending on how you use it.

Comment: @hp001 It will function just fine how you have it. It's more a matter of design and making your code easier to change. If you're interested in learning more, I strongly recommend Sandi Metz's book, [Practical OO Design in Ruby](http://amzn.to/29C7hlJ).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

```
def show
  @client  = Client.find params[:id]
  @workers = @client.workers
end
```

Assuming you are using resourceful routing, the `params` hash will include the id portion of the URL path, which, here, is `/clients/:id`.  So, you can use that to find the specific client in question, then get the works for that client.

But there's plenty of details on this topic that you'll probably want to read here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I like this code. It's very easy to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should define a has_many relationship between client and workers.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workers
end

class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

More info: [Active Record has_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Then in the 'show' action you should get workers that are related for particular user. For example:

```
# GET /clients/1
# GET /clients/1.json
def show
  user = User.find(params[:id]) # find specific user
  @workers = user.workers # get workers related to this user

  # or you can do something like this
  @workers = Worker.where(user_id: params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I like the second option. It looks like I can do everything in one line of code. Awesome!